# Dismiss ViewController presented modally when tab is changed

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UITableViewController`that presents a `UIViewController` modally when `didSelectRowAt`is invoked.

My application is wrapped in a `UITabBarController`.

I would like to dismiss the `UIViewController` when a user changes tabs.

I have tried to call `dismiss` on my controller like so, but this does not work.

```
let vc = VimeoController() 
....    

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        vc.dismiss(animated: true) {
            print("dismissed")
        }

    }
...
    fileprivate func presentModal() -> Void {
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your dismiss call within the [viewDidDisappear](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621477-viewdiddisappear) lifecycle hook of your `VimeoController` controller instead.

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```